# The most recent email notification doesn't show correctly OS X Mail (with threads turned on)

Tags: bug, notifications, email, osx

The problem occurs when you are using Mail - OS X, and you have email threads turned on. For some reason the first email is always shown as empty... until I actually double click on the email and open it.

[image]

Comment: This is a Mail feature; it hides text it deems quoted from previous mails in the thread. This is **not** something that Stack Exchange emails can change.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I feel like there is some work around that SE can implement, so OS X Mail doesn't interpret the contents of the email as quoted.

Comment: @Martijn thats just a failure of imagination, I'm sure we could include some sort of self replicating program to rewrite major parts of the user's system enforcing the full display of our data

Comment: @Arian why should a website make a special changes for users of a specific OS and Mail program when the problem appears to be in how the OS and Mail program operate?

Comment: @RichardTingle: And where will this adjustment for individual mail applications then stop? GMail has similar functionality, but implemented differently again. And what if the Apple Mail algorithm is adjusted and more changes are needed?

Comment: @Martijn I clearly need to work harder on my jokes

Comment: @RichardTingle: Hehe, I need to work harder on my joke detecting. :-P